# jQuery Ajax jSon set value from database based on condition on loop

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have jQuery json to get data from database.

```
var list = ["Imsak", "Subuh", "Terbit", "Dhuhur", "Ashar", "Maghrib", "Isya"];

geo = [jsonStr.longitude, jsonStr.latitude, jsonStr.altitude];
timezone = jsonStr.timezone;

prayTimes.tune({ imsak: 2, subuh: 2, terbit: -2, dhuhur: 121, ashar: 2, maghrib: 2, isya: 2 });

var date = new Date(); // today 
prayTimes.setMethod(jsonStr.calculationMethod);
var times = prayTimes.getTimes(date, geo, timezone);

$.ajax(
{
    url: "chk",
    type: "POST",
    data:
    {
    },
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (jsonStr)
    {
        var sholatNameLen = jsonStr.sholatName.length;
        for(var i=0; i<sholatNameLen; i++)
        {
            var sholatName = jsonStr.sholatName[i];

            if(jsonStr.time10 == times[list[i].toLowerCase()] + ":00")
            {
                if(list[i] == sholatName)
                {
                    alert(jsonStr.audio_before_adzan);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

On my table, I have data

```
sholat_name  | audio_before_adzan | iqamah
Subuh        | Alfatihah.mp3      | 10
Dhuhur       | Al-Baqarah.mp3     | 10
```

On my PHP jSon

```
$time10 = date("H:i:s", strtotime('+ 10 minutes'));
$qAdzanIqomah = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tb_sholat WHERE active = 'Y'");
while($dAdzanIqomah = mysqli_fetch_array($qAdzanIqomah))
{
    $sholatName[] = $dAdzanIqomah['sholat_name'];
    $iqamah[] = $dAdzanIqomah['iqamah'];
    $audio_before_adzan[] = $dAdzanIqomah['audio_before_adzan'];
}

$data = array(
    "audio_before_adzan"     => $audio_before_adzan,
    'time10' => $time10
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

What I want is, when `if(jsonStr.time10 == times[list[i].toLowerCase()] + ":00")` is true then get audio_before_adzan based on sholatName.

I tried the above code, but this function `if(list[i] == sholatName)`  is not correct maybe.

Comment: from where u r getting jsonStr.time10 & times[]

Comment: Same question as @imtiyazahmed: where do you get the time10 data from?

Comment: All, sorry missing it... updated now

Comment: Hi @HiDayurie. I wonder if I could ask you to make your posts a bit less chatty? We like questions to be succinct here, so there is no need to add "please advice" to everything you write - readers do know you are looking for help! (In any case, "please advice" is wrong is spelling and grammatical terms also, FWIW).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're just messing up your for-loops. You seem to use the same variable  `i` for 2 different loops. You should split the loops for it to be useful:

The code below is only the part in the `success`-function:

```
var sholatNameLen = jsonStr.sholatName.length;
    for(var i=0; i<sholatNameLen; i++)
    {
        var sholatName = jsonStr.sholatName[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < list.lenght; j++) {
             if(jsonStr.time10 == times[list[j].toLowerCase()] + ":00")
             {

                if(list[j] == sholatName)
                {
                    alert(jsonStr.audio_before_adzan[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```